# Send form inside function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to transform a ContentEditable area in a form element with Javascript, and after the Editable content loses focus, the form is automatically sent. For some reason, the javascript is not working with the two commands, and the form is not being sent.

JS:

```
<script>
function sendform() {
  document.getElementById("search-hidden").value = document.getElementById("search").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form id='Form' action='handle.php' method='post'>
<p id="search" contenteditable='true' onblur="sendform()">Search</p>
<input id='search-hidden' type='hidden' name='search-hidden'>
</form>
```

Comment: ops, i just updated the code, Still not working though

Comment: Open your JS console (F12), and tell us if you see any error.

Comment: that was it, thanks!

Comment: What was it? If you've discovered the solution on your own, please post it as an answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Previously a user commented that my form had an ID of "form" instead of "myForm" as called by the JS, but apparently he deleted the comment.